# Algebra: $a \cdot b = 2^{ab}$, associative property

Tags: abstract-algebra

Lets say, I have a binary operation $\cdot$ and an operation $a \cdot b = 2^{a b}$ defined on the set $\mathbb{N}$.

How can I prove that this operation is non-/associative? 
$(a \cdot b) \cdot c= a \cdot (b \cdot c)$

I know that if I have $a \cdot b = a^b$, then it would look like this: $(a^b)^c \ne a^{(b^c)}$. 
For example: 
$(2^1)^2 = 4$

$2^{(1^2)} = 2$

and so this is not associative, but how would the above equation be like?

Comment: Have you tried plugging in some small values for a,b,c, on both sides of (a•b)•c=a•(b•c)? Which values did you try and what did you get?

Comment: Try $a=0$, $b=1$ and $c=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
(a\cdot b)\cdot c=(2^{a*b})\cdot c=2^{(c*2^{a*b})}\\
a\cdot(b\cdot c)=a\cdot (2^{b*c})=2^{(a*2^{b*c})}
$$
In general, $a*2^{b*c}\neq c*2^{a*b}$. So we're done.